# Having issues scrolling vertically in a horizontal screen orientation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have currently ran into another issue while trying to fix my horizontal scrolling on this app screen. I had a [previous question and error that I presented on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246184/trying-to-fix-bottom-overflow-with-flutter-layout) which got answered about an overflow issue I was having. The solution was to add a scroll which fixed the issue, but created a new issue. So is there anyway to take my current code presented below or the code in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246184/trying-to-fix-bottom-overflow-with-flutter-layout) to fix the issue seen in the pictures I submitted below? Thank you for all your help!

Edit: The images I provided show the scrolling going past the intended point. The ListTiles shouldn't go behind the other Containers as a background. They should just vanish when hitting the top of the blue section.
The app is meant to be used in a vertical view, but this section of code I would also like to work in a horizontal view. I had to create the scroll so that the page wouldn't overflow with pixels, but now it causes the ListTiles to display behind the question and Example sections when you scroll up. Is there a way to get the ListTiles to keep vertically scrolling so it works properly for both vertical and horizontal phone orientations.

[image: Image of my horizontal scrolling before any scrolling]

[image: Image of my horizontal scrolling after scrolling]

**Current Code quiz.dart**

```dart
class Salvation extends StatefulWidget {
  const Salvation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Salvation> createState() => _SalvationState();
}

class _SalvationState extends State<Salvation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Quiz')),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight / 4,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 8),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text('Question',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            )),
                      ))),
              Visibility(
                // visible: ,
                child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight / 4,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 3, 12, 6),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(118, 60, 51, 0.5),
                        ),
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 8),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('Example/Image Box',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17.0,
                                  )),
                              // RichText(text: text)
                              Text('Hello there',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(155, 205, 255, 0.8),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 20),
                    child: ListView(children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option A'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option B'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option C'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                            onLongPress: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option D'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    )),
              
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can u explain the issue in brief

Comment: I'll edit the post with this, however the images I provided show the scrolling going past the intended point. The ListTiles shouldn't go behind the other Containers as a background. They should just vanish when hitting the top of the blue section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept the Answer if its helpful

1. i have added a simple example
2. the simplest way is to add your column in card view, then it will scroll only in card view
   or if you dont want to use card view
3. you have to add width and color to container and it will work

```
class Test1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Quiz")),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
// here color and width added to container (optional: If you dont want to use card view)
              width: Get.width,
              // color: Colors.red,
              height: 200,
              child: Text("Question"),
            ),
            Container(
              // color: Colors.white,
              width: Get.width,

              height: 200,
              child: Text("Image Box"),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
// here a card view added... it will solve your problem
                  child: Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [

                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option A'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option B'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option C'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option D'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option E'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 6),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Option F'),
                            tileColor: const Color.fromRGBO(6, 145, 248, 1),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black, width: 10),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[![output image]

[image]

Comment: I used the card view portion and it really helped so thank you! I now need to edit my page to adjust for the color and padding differences, but thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think This Will Work if Work please mark as accepted..

***code:***

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-60.0;
    double width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Quiz')),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: width,
            height: height/3,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 10,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Tile No ${index+1}'),
                      tileColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: width,
            height:height/3,
            child: Container(color: Colors.white,),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: width,
            height: height/3,
            child: Container(color: Colors.yellow,),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

***OutPut in image:***

[image]

***Scenario for Column..***

```
Column(),//it's allow multiple Childs Vertical by default it have not scroll property.

SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(),), // now with the help of Parent Widget column can scrollable.
```

***Same Scenario is for Row()***

```
Row(), //it's allow multiple Childs Horizontal by default it have not scroll
SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, child:Row(),)// now with the help of Parent Widget row can scrollable in Horizontal Direction.
```

***Scenario for ListView()***

```
ListView(),//It's allow us to assign multiple childs with scroll property vertically but we can change the scrolldirection to horizontal
```

**Now it's Up to You which widget is help full for you to remove the bottom over flex issue**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However going through each scenario, I used to have just a Column, but it would cause my app to overflow by 194 pixels. Switching to a SingleChildScrollView causes the same issues with overflow. Switching or adding `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` for both SingleChildScrollView and ListView causes the app screen to go black and throw over 100 exceptions in the terminal.